# ASIHTTPRequest error bad URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, asihttprequest

I've been searching for this problem for a while now. I'm trying to update the value of xml node with ASIHTTPRequest. This code should send a request but it always returns me:

```
Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Unable to create request (bad url?)"
```

So I've tried to encode my URL like many answers on this site and others proposed and nothing worked so far... I've tried this :

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

as well as this one :

```
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes
```

I've also tried this :

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.123.143:50003/Courbe.xml"; 
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:urlString]];
```

And I'm always getting the same error.
This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
NSString *url = @"http://192.168.123.143:50003/Courbe.xml"; 
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addPostValue:@"111" forKey:@"tempset"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Those are my delegate methods:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

Anyone can help me solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`requestWithURL:` requires an NSURL as a parameter, but you are passing an NSString.

Try using this corrected code:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.123.143:50003/Courbe.xml"; 
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:urlString]];
```

Comment: Still giving me the same error...I'll be back to try anything else tomorrow if you have any other idea. And thanks for this info about NSURL instead of NSString

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initialize `url` which you use in  `[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url]`?

Comment: Yeah little typo from me I've been trying too much stuff, my bad its the 1st line i'll edit it